# Pterodactyl Panel additional subdomain pointing to Discord bot server

Tags: node.js, nginx, dns, directadmin

I apologize in advance if this makes no sense at all.

I'm currently working on a public Discord bot, and I want it's settings to run through a web dashboard.
I set up a panel using `discord-dashboard` as it was designed to work, and hosted it on my Pterodactyl Panel.

However, my panel runs on a subdomain (sub1.example.com), and now I'm trying to point a different subdomain (sub2.example.com) to the same IP, but using a SRV record to point to the bot's hosted server, in the hope of seeing the dashboard.

Instead, I see the login page of the Pterodactyl panel.

The panel is self-hosted on a VPS, and uses NGINX to run.

Is there any way of doing this properly?